# ioquake 3 no enemies appear whatsoever

Tags: technical-issues, pc, quake-3

I recently installed ioquake3 on a fresh install of CentOS 7 (64-bit) with all the *.pk3 files from the original game CD-ROM properly installed.

The game starts fine but **no enemies appear in any of the arenas**.  The ioquake3 help site and even an all-out Google search have failed me here.

Can anyone please help me figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be common with the Linux version of ioquake, and in those cases, people suggest trying a test build:

> This is a known issue with the 1.36 stable release for GNU/Linux x86_64.
>   **Install a [test build](https://ioquake3.org/get-it/test-builds/) to fix it**.
>   <sup>[1](https://discourse.ioquake.org/t/single-player-no-bots/1173/2), [2](https://github.com/ioquake/ioq3/issues/373)</sup>

<sup>(Note that for me, the test builds link was down for a while as I was writing this post. Just try again later.)</sup>

Another solution is given [here](https://discourse.ioquake.org/t/some-maps-in-single-player-mode-dont-have-bots/537):

> As I could read in some forums, a lot of Linux users are having the same bug. I fixed it **uninstalling all the ioquake3 packages and installing the quake3 official packages**.

If you have a 64-bit system, the following reaction at the end of that same thread offers another, more convoluted, alternative:

> Unfortunately we don’t currently have an ioquake3 test build for 32bit systems, surprisingly it turns out to be easier to cross-compile a build for 32bit windows under 64bit Linux than to do so for a 32bit Linux!
>
> **You could use [this shell script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ioquake/ioq3/master/misc/linux/server_compile.sh) to download and install a version of ioquake3 from git.** Just change the `BUILD_CLIENT="0"` to `BUILD_CLIENT="1"` and you can also change the `COPYDIR` to wherever you’d like the ioquake3 installation to go. You’ll also need various prerequisites to compile like *make*, *gcc*, et cetera.

---

[Here](http://tiggeron.blogspot.com/2014/07/linux-ioquake3-64bit-with-bot-support.html)'s an interesting blog entry, where the author explains what he did in order to get it running. His introduction to the problem:

> Interestingly, the Linux 64bit version of ioquake3 only kind-of works. Basically, the engine will start and everything will render correctly, but bot's don't load at all.
>
> I did not look at the code, but it is possible this is a compiler error for the binaries that are on the ioquake3 site for download. My thinking behind this is because of the log errors when adding a bot seem too wrong and because my compile from source version does work. The console errors look like:
>
> `Error: file/bots/default_c.c line 2: file charsh" not found`
>   `Warning: couldn't find skill 5 in bots/default_c.c`
>
> I believe *charsh* should be *chars.h*. Anyway, let's fix this up so we can play Quake 3 :]

You can compile the fixes yourself, or download them directly from [here](http://lvlworld.com/lvl/ioquake3_64bit.zip).
Credit goes to [*tiggeron.blogspot.com*](http://tiggeron.blogspot.com/) (I wasn't able to find a username).